# python rabbitMQ consumer which consumes a message and calls an API running as a background process

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a simple use case where i want to consume messages from a RabbitMQ server, this messages are generated by third party application and whenever they generate any message i want my consumer to recieve it and make an API call.

I have got the below script to solve the problem but I am not sure if it is a production level solution, is there any way I can improve it or will it work fine if i run this script in background with the help of supervisor.

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', 5672, '/', 
                                     pika.PlainCredentials("user", "pass")))
channel = connection.channel()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    #Makes an API call

channel.basic_consume(queue="notifications.info", on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that pretty much it. For production, you can implement `multiprocessing` and multiple consumers to scale out the solution.